# Can minions have negative power?

Tags: smash-up

For instance Mr. Grumpers from the Kitty Cat faction says

> Choose a minion. It has -2 power until the end of the turn

Can a minion be rendered with negative power, or is it always at least zero as one might expect in a realistic attack situation--you know, one of Zombies, Pirates, Dinosaurs and Kitty Cats attacking an alien home world.

Glymmer from the Fairy faction has this power

> Talent: Until the start of your next turn, either another minion has -4 power (minimum power 0), OR this minion has +1 power.

Can I play Glymmer, and then, on my next turn, use his talent to force another minion to 0 power, then play Mr Grumpers to send him to -2 because there is no "minimum power 0" clause in Mr. Grumpers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

While the core rules don't answer this, it is explicitly covered in the expansions. From the most recent expansion, [Pretty Pretty Smash Up](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2014/11/SU7_Rulebook.pdf), page 12:

> The power of a minion not in play is only the number printed on it, but
>   once in play its power includes all modifications. **Its power may never go below zero.**

Comment: So if some minion had a base power of 2, then received both -4 and +2 "buffs" would its resulting power be 0 or 2? The rule you quote seems to indicate it would be 2, though had I been asked the question without the rule bold and in front of me I would have said 0.

Comment: It'd end up at 0, because the -4 modifier is still active; the minion's overall power just has a floor of 0. The minion is a 0 power minion, based on a 2-power minion with -4. When the +2 comes in, we look at the modifiers on it, and we find a 2-power minion with -4 +2, making it a 0-power minion.