# Order of Operations on Actions

Tags: smash-up

If a **First Mate** (power of 2) has been poisoned

> [...] Ongoing: This minion has -4 power. (Minions have minimum power of 0.)

Also, if a **Howl** action card has been played

> Each of your minions gains +1 power until the end of your turn.

How much power is the card worth after **Howl** has been played?

Is the +1 from **Howl** added before **Poison**? After **Poison**? Or are all modifiers added up at any given time during the turn?

- (Base 2 - Poison 4 + Howl 1) = -1 –> Min of zero
- (Base 2 - Poison 4 (Min of zero)) + Howl 1) = 1

Do cards with minimums apply before other actions, or do they adhere to the commutative property of addition?

Comment: Good point, updated to make more clear (hopefully)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/24488/can-minions-have-negative-power), you add up the modifiers acting on the minion.

> The power of a minion not in play is only the number printed on it, but once in play its power includes all modifications. Its power may never go below zero.

So you add up all the modifications, and if it's below 0 at the end, it's 0 instead. If a new modification comes in, you reevalute.